# Не выводить родителя, если нет дочерних

Tags: алгоритм

В шаблоне ember выводится информация:

```
{{#each model.item1 as |item1|}}
    {{item1.title}}
    {{#each item1.item2 as |item2|}}
        {{item2.title}}
        {{#each item2.item3 as |item3|}}
            {{item3.title}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы если `item3.title` нулевой, то не выводился `item2.title`. А если и `item2.title` нулевой, то чтоб не выводился `item1.title`. Т.е. если нету дочерних элементов, то и не выводить родителя. Мне бы понять алгоритм.

Comment: Ну чисто схематично `{each x as xx} IF NOT xx IS EMPTY {xx.title} {each xx as xxx} IF NOT xxx IS EMPTY {xxx.title} ... {/each}`. А есть там IF, как проверить на отсутствие дочек и как оно всё правильно пишется - разбирайтесь сами...

Answer (score 0):

Надо сбросить флажок вывода, а потом в цикле по дочкам попытаться его поднять.
Если флажок вывода поднялся, тогда дочки есть, и можно выводить.
А если остался сброшенным, то дочек нет, и выводить не надо.

Comment: Подошло бы, если бы мама выводилась после дочек. Но она выводится перед ними - что, два раза дочек перекапывать?

Comment: Можно хранить массив флажков, чтобы каждая дочка распоряжалась своим флажком.
Если дочек немного, то лучше использовать слово - чтобы каждая дочка распоряжалась своим битом, а мама проверяла на нуль.

Comment: Это неправильно, когда экземпляр сущности пытается управлять атрибутами другого экземпляра сущности напрямую. Я понимаю, если бы было предложено "дочке" дёрнуть "маму" за метод "мама, теперь у тебя есть я" - но мама скорее всего и так знает о наличии дочек, ибо все они есть её атрибут. Кстати, не исключено, что у каждого itemX доступно свойство itemX.subItems.Count, которое вполне можно использовать вместо предложенной мной выше проверки `IS EMPTY`, сравнивая с нулём.

Comment: Если так, то нечего и огород городить